# IE7 strong tag behave like block element

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I've got this structure:

```
<li>
<strong>If the Technology Developer and Analyst Intern Program - Consumer Banking Technology & Operations (CBT&O) is NOT conducting interviews on your campus,<strong> please apply below between November 1st and January 2nd.
</li>
```

In all browsers it looks fine, but in IE7 (and IE7 compability mode) looks like on [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/kK4Ro9Gs).(http://screencast.com/t/kK4Ro9Gs)

Comment: As @Wololo said, check your tag closures. Just copy everything into W3C validator to make sure that's correct first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `<strong>` element looks like a block with a fixed width in IE7. I recommend you embedding [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or a [css reset](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) so this doesn't happen.

If it doesn't work, try also to give css to the strong element, maybe something like `display:inline; float:left, width:100%`

I don't have the website to mess around, so you have to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. IE7 was automatically setting `zoom:1` for strong element. I overwrited it with `zoom:normal` and it fixed it.